# How to trim out the \x part of the array elements?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a hex array buffer[]. From eclipse I can see that the values are stored in the array as:

```
['\x03', '\x9f', '\x04', '\x9f']
```

I want to cut the \x part of it and just want the array as (hex array):

```
[03, 9f, 04, 9f]
```

I tried the format option:

```
hex(buffer[0][2:])
```

Just to check if it is getting formatted, but it doesn't. Any help to convert the whole array to my expected output format?

Comment: `[03, 9f, 04, 9f]` is not a valid Python literal.  Did you mean `['03', '9f', '04', '9f']`, which is a list of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = ['\x03', '\x9f', '\x04', '\x9f']
print(['{:02x}'.format(ord(i)) for i in l])
```

This outputs:

```
['03', '9f', '04', '9f']
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert this list of characters to hex? ie, to an array of [03,9f, 04, 9f]?

Comment: If you mean to convert the list to simply `[0x03, 0x9f, 0x04, 0x9f]`, then all you need is to get the ordinal value of each character, with: `[ord(i) for i in l]`

Comment: Can't I have a hex array? with ord() it stores the value as integers.. For eg, hex value 85 is stored as 133.

Comment: No you can't. You have to store hexes as strings; otherwise they're simply stored as integers.

Comment: Okay. thanks for the information. Now is it possible to swap two values in adjacent array indexes say for eg, index [0] with value 0x03, and [1] with value 0x9f, to read it as 9f03 and then convert it to an int value (40707)?

Comment: @user5105767 Use a loop to retrieve 2 elements a time, multiply the second by 256 and add onto the first and you get it. Not so hard to think of

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
buffer = ['\x03', '\x9f', '\x04', '\x9f']
output = ['%02x' % ord(x[0]) for x in buffer]
print(output) # ['03', '9f', '04', '9f']
```

Elements in your original list are one-char strings. To get their hexadecimal char values you use `ord()` and format with `%x`.

Answer (score 0):

Encode each value of the array:

```
arr = ['\x03', '\x9f', '\x04', '\x9f']
map(lambda x: x.encode('hex'), arr)
# ['03', '9f', '04', '9f']
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert this list of characters to hex? ie, to an array of [03,9f, 04, 9f]?

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer is a list of characters.  For example, '\x03' is the character with ordinal value 0x03.

Here's how to get the output you wanted:

```
b = ['\x03', '\x9f', '\x04', '\x9f']
result = [format(ord(i), "02x") for i in b]
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert this list of characters to hex? ie, to an array of [03,9f, 04, 9f]?